# C++ program significantly slower when run in bash

Tags: c++, bash, terminal, ubuntu-12.04

I have a query regarding bash. I have been running some of my own C++ programs in conjunction with commercial programs and controlling their interaction (via input and output files) through Bash scripting. I am finding that if I run my c++ program alone in terminal it completes in around 10–15 seconds, but when I run the same through the bash script it can take up to 5 minutes to complete in each case.

I find using System Monitor that consistently 100% of one CPU is used when I run the program directly in terminal whereas when I run it in bash (in a loop) a maximum of 60% of CPU usage is recorded and seems to be linked to the longer completion time (although the average CPU usage is higher over the 4 processors).

This is quite frustrating as until recently this was not a problem.

An example of the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
DIR="$1"
TRCKDIR=$DIR/TRCKRSLTS
STRUCTDIR=$DIR
SHRTTRCKDIR=$TRCKDIR/SHRT_TCK_FILES
VTAL=VTAL.png
VTAR=VTAR.png

NAL=$(find $STRUCTDIR | grep NAL)
NAR=$(find $STRUCTDIR | grep NAR)
AMYL=$(find $STRUCTDIR | grep AMYL)
AMYR=$(find $STRUCTDIR | grep AMYR)
TCKFLS=($(find $TRCKDIR -maxdepth 1 | grep .fls))

numTCKFLS=${#TCKFLS[@]}

for i in $(seq 0 $[numTCKFLS-1]); do

    filenme=${TCKFLS[i]}
    filenme=${filenme%.t*}
    filenme=${filenme##*/}      

    if [[ "$filenme" == *VTAL* ||  "$filenme" == *VTA_L* ]]; then

        STREAMLINE_CUTTER -MRT ${TCKFLS[i]} -ROI1 $VTAL -ROI2 $NAL  -op "$SHRTTRCKDIR"/"$filenme"_VTAL_NAL.fls
        STREAMLINE_CUTTER -MRT ${TCKFLS[i]} -ROI1 $VTAL -ROI2 $AMYL  -op "$SHRTTRCKDIR"/"$filenme"_VTAL_AMYL.fls

    fi

    if [[ "$filenme" == *VTAR* ||  "$filenme" == *VTA_R* ]];then

        STREAMLINE_CUTTER -MRT ${TCKFLS[i]} -ROI1 $VTAR -ROI2 $NAR  -op "$SHRTTRCKDIR"/"$filenme"_VTAR_NAR.fls
        STREAMLINE_CUTTER -MRT ${TCKFLS[i]} -ROI1 $VTAR -ROI2 $AMYR  -op "$SHRTTRCKDIR"/"$filenme"_VTAR_AMYR.fls

    fi

done
```

Comment: Have you profiled both the script and program (stand-alone and in unison) to check where the delay is? I doubt if the input/environment is exactly same!!!

Comment: I have placed a simple comment inside the c++ code to time each section and it seems to be a problem within the loop, when in terminal it takes 10 times less than when run in bash

Comment: I would like to close the question. My problem was as kumar_m_kiran stated the test input/environment was not exactly the same as the actual used environment. One of the files was located on an external disk drive which seemed to significantly slow the processing time (this file I copied to the desktop for the test). This miss was due to a lack of thoroughness on my part. Thank you kumar_m_kiran for the clue.